# Spring string to enum converter accepts empty strings

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have the following `string` to `enum` converter factory:

```
public final class StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum<?>> {

  public <T extends Enum<?>> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
    return new StringToEnumConverter(targetType);
  }

  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  private static final class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T> {

    private final Class<T> enumType;

    public T convert(String source) {
      try {
        return Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.toUpperCase().trim());
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Argument invalid " + source);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I've implemented the following controller:

```
public interface GetGraphsController {
  @GetMapping(value = "/graphs", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  Graphs getGraphs(@RequestParam GraphType graphType);
}
```

`GraphType` corresponds to the following `enum`:

```
public enum GraphType {
  A,
  B;
}
```

Since `graphType` is required, I expect Spring to throw an exception when requesting `/graphs?graphType=` (note no `graphType` is included). However, passing no `graphType` is allowed, and no error is thrown.

I've also tried adding the following condition to `convert`, but the result is the same:

```
if (source.isBlank()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Argument invalid " + source);
}
```

Comment: What's the value that's passed into your controller method?

Comment: What happens if you use this `Graphs getGraphs(@RequestParam("graphType") GraphType graphType)`

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- `null`

Comment: What happens if you apply `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` to the method parameter?

Comment: Sounds strange, double check that the correct method is invoked. Check that the implementing class does not "override" the annotations and does not add a second method mapped to "/graphs" without required `graphType` parameter. - also check that your Converter is invoked at all.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- exactly the same as before

Comment: @g.momo the parameter is set to `null` and the controller continues normal execution

Comment: @Ralph already checked. No overriding nor second methods exist and the converter is indeed invoked. The thing I found is the exception is thrown, but apparently the converter handles it automatically and converts the empty string to `null` using `TypeConverterDelegate` method `convertIfNecessary`. But again, since `RequestParam` does not allow null values, this should never continue normal execution...

Comment: @thmasker can you share your pom.xml with us ? In my side, after testing `@RequestParam('graphType")` null was automatically rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it by adding `@Validated` to the controller interface and `@NotNull` to `graphType`. Apparently without those annotations validation is not made. `@RequestParam` has a `required` field (`true` by default) which only checks if the query parameter is included in the request and does not care about its value